# How to find complex numbers such that this list is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Show that if we think of $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$, then the list $(1+i,1-i)$ is linearly dependent.

I need to find two complex numbers $a+bi$ and $c+di$, both not $0$ such that

$$(a+bi)(1+i) + (c+di)(1-i) = 0.$$

Now:

\begin{align*}
a+ai+bi-b+c-ci+di-d&=0
\\
(a+c)+i(a-c)+i(b+d)-(b+d)&=0
\\
(a+c)+i(a-c)&=(b+d)-i(b+d)
\end{align*}

I know the solution but I don’t know what I need to do to get to it. Maybe I’m missing something really obvious. Any pointers or solutions is appreciated.

Comment: Let $a= 1+i$ and $b=1-i$.  Then note that $\frac{1}{a}\cdot a + \frac{-1}{b}\cdot b = 0$.

Comment: You don't have to do any computation if you recognize that the dimension of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb C$ is $1$. This implies that any list of more than one "vector" must be linearly dependent.

Comment: @bungo oh that's a good thought I forgot about it, so since (a+bi) spans c then any list > size 1 is dependant in C

Comment: Right, any nonzero $z \in \mathbb C$ spans $\mathbb C$, since any other $w \in \mathbb C$ can be written as a scalar multiple of $z$, namely $w = az$ where $a = z^{-1}w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we multiply $1+i$ by $1-i$ we get the same number as when we multiply $1-i$ by $1+i$. Consequently,

$$
(1+i)(1-i) - (1-i)(1+i) = 0.
$$

Comparing to

$$
(1+i)(a+ib) + (1-i)(c+di) = 0
$$

we see that we can set $a=1$ and $b=c=d=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda=\frac{1-i}{1+i}=-i$. Then $\lambda(1+i)-(1-i)=0$, and therefore $1-i$ and $1+i$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

To solve $z_1(1 + i) + z_2(1-i) = 0$, 
take $z_1 =$ any complex number such that 
$z_1 \neq 0 \implies z_1(1 + i) \neq 0.$

Then, $z_2 = - \frac{z_1(1 + i)}{1-i}.$

Answer (score 0):

Any field $K$ is $1$-dimensional when viewed as a $K$-vector space: let $x, y \in K$, then, if either of $x$ or $y$ is $0$, say $x$, then $1x + 0 y = 0$, otherwise they are both non-zero, and then $x^{-1}x + (-1)y^{-1}y = 1 - 1 = 0$. So two distinct elements of the field $\Bbb{C}$ do not form a linearly independent set.